# javascript - how to get img tags from any element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get img tags attribute values from any element, img tags could be more than 1, and also can be randomized.
like,

```
<div> hellow <img src='icons/smile.png' title=':)'> how are u <img src='icons/smile2.png' title=':D'></div>
```

I want to grab their `title` attribute values and then want to store in some `var currentHTML;` with all existing div data.

and then insert into any element just like `$('#div').html(currentHTML);`

and output should be like this,

```
 hellow :) how are u :D
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this? thats why I asked.
what I thought how to do this, I think it needs some loop.

Comment: You should read the [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which explains that you should show what you have tried before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("img").each(function()
{
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).prop("title"));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dst9wdau/1/). Its just looping through each image and replacing it (with [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)) with its own `title` attribute.

*UPDATE:*

Things got more complex. Check [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/dst9wdau/4/):

```
// The text result you want
var currentHTML = "";

// Instead of search for each image, we can search of elements that 
// contains images and you want to get their text
$(".images").each(function()
{
    // Check note #1
    var cloned = $(this).clone().css("display", "none").appendTo($("body"));

    // Here we select all images from the cloned element to what 
    // we did before: replace them with their own titles
    cloned.find("img").each(function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).prop("title"));
    });

    // Add the result to the global result text
    currentHTML+= cloned.html();
});

// After all, just set the result to the desired element's html
$("#div").html(currentHTML);
```

*Note #1:* Here is what is happening in that line:

- `var cloned =` here we create a var which will receive a cloned element;
- the cloned element will the current element [`$(this).clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/);
- this element must be hidden [`.css("display", "none")`](http://api.jquery.com/css/);
- and then appended to the document's body [`.appendTo($("body"));`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

Note that in your initial html, the `div` containing the images received the class `images`:

```
<div class="images"> hellow <img src='icons/smile.png' title=':)' /> how are u <img src='icons/smile2.png' title=':D' /></div>
```

So you can do that on more than one element. I hope this helps.

Comment: but this fiddle has no output like that as it desired I asked, like 
hellow :) how are u :D

Comment: if you add `console.log(currentHTML);`  or alert it, you will see that it is returning the title tags

Comment: I know that, but how can I use them like this, `hellow :) how are u :D` ??

Comment: this is working good, but how this is achieved? :/ I don't get it, can you please explain me ??

Comment: @hsn0331 as said in the `replaceWith()` docs: *Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content*. So all image elements are replaced in the parent(the `div`) element by another content, which I chose to be their own `title` attribute.

Comment: what a great answer :D hahahahah, thank you, u don't deserve downvote, u got upvote :D

Comment: @hsn0331 in fact, that method is new to me. I learn it researching to answer your question. Nice question, thanks.

Comment: but this is returning object `[object Object]` :(

Comment: @hsn0331 it returns a collection with the removed elements, please read the docs.

Comment: but I only need result

Comment: but I don't want to replace that before, I want the result to store in variable and then use that back. :(

Comment: @hsn0331 one question: you want all images in a specific element, right? Or there is more elements with images?

Comment: this function and method has bug, if the multiple imgs are present at time each next to, then replacement method didn't work correct, like
`<img src='icons/smile.png' title=':)' /><img src='icons/smile2.png' title=':D' />`
and result is, `:):)` instead of `:):D`

Comment: yeh, it wasn't before, but I checked it again, and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat little function you can reuse.

```js
$(function(){

  function getImageReplace($el) {
    var $copy = $el.clone();
    $copy.find('img').each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('title'));
    });
    return $copy.text();
  }

  //now you can use this on any div element you like
  $('#go').click(function() {
    alert(getImageReplace($('div')));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> hellow <img src='icons/smile.png' title=':)'> how are u <img src='icons/smile2.png' title=':D'></div>   
<button id='go'>Convert images</button>
```

Comment: this function and method has bug, if the multiple imgs are present at time each next to, then replacement method didn't work correct, like
`<img src='icons/smile.png' title=':)' /><img src='icons/smile2.png' title=':D' />`
and result is, `:):)` instead of `:):D`

Comment: this funciton is also append `Replycancel` with result

Comment: I dont see that bug, if your div contains other elements you'll need to modify the code to suit your purposes. I'm offering a *method* to solve your problem.

Comment: your method is similar to @DontVoteMeDown and works fine in regular example, but what I said and explain that is not happening.